# Half-Life 1 menus not appearing (Linux Version)

Tags: games, steam

This is not the wine version of the game, it is through the linux version of steam. Whenever I load up the original Half-Life game I do not get any menus. I have tried using `-soft` as a Launch Option but that changes nothing. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the game.

How do I get menus in Half-Life?

Edit 1: Uninstalled and reinstalled graphics driver, changes nothing.

Comment: They just appear when I start the game. It sounds like maybe you need to contact Valve support to report the issue to them.